# Building Multi-Tenant Rails Apps With MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, multi-tenant

Please let me know link article or tutorial available for Implementing Multitenant in Ruby on Rails With MySQL !

this blog for postgresql.
http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps you.

http://blog.codecrate.com/2011/03/multitenant-locking-down-your-app-and.html

https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant